# Compiling C++ non-type template parameters outside headers?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

This may be a silly question, but I have been struggling with this problem, and ChatGPT solutions aren't able to solve it.

I have the following class definition:

```
template<typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<int, U>>>
class TestClass {
  public:
    auto print() -> void;
};
```

If I implement print() within the declaration / header itself, this is trivial:

```
template<typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<U, int>, int> = 0>
class TestClass
{
    auto print()
    {
       std::cout << "Hello";
    }
};
```

However, if I try to move this into a cpp file for it's implementation, I cannot get it to compile. Here is one of my attempts:

```
template<typename U, typename>
void TestClass<U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<int, U>>>::print()
{
    std::cout << "Printing from TestClass" << std::endl;
}
```

And here is that attempt's compilation error:

```
main.cpp:14:19: error: template argument for non-type template parameter must be an expression
void TestClass<U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<int, U>>>::print()
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:6:71: note: template parameter is declared here
template<typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<U, int>, int> = 0>
                                                                      ^
1 error generated.
```

What is the correct syntax when moving this into a cpp file?

Comment: You have swapped `U` and `int` in the first and second class template definition. Also, fundamental types have no bases and can not be bases

Comment: But you understand you'll then need explicit instantiations to avoid `undefined reference`s, right?

Comment: *"What is the correct syntax when moving this into a cpp file?"* -- For the error you presented, this question would be better phrased as "What is the correct syntax when moving this **out of the class definition**?" Once you have the syntax for moving the function definition out of the class definition (but still in the header), you can deal with [the separate concerns of moving a templated entity into a source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common way of doing this(**syntax-wise**) is to specify the default argument in the first occurrence of the definition/declaration and ommit it in the next as shown below.

This means that there are ***two ways to solve this*** depending upon which of the two code snippets given in your question you're using.

##### Method 1

```
//specify default argument here
template<typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<int, U>>>
class TestClass {
  public:
    auto print() -> void;
};
//no default argument here
template<typename U, typename N>
void TestClass<U, N>::print() 
{
       std::cout << "Hello"; 
}
```

[working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EPj9GWK9e)

##### Method 2

```
//specify the default argument here
template<typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<U, int>, int> = 0>
class TestClass
{
    auto print() -> void;
    
};
//no need to specify default argument here
template<typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<U, int>, int> N>
void TestClass<U, N>::print()
{
       std::cout << "Hello";
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Mx4jTrjEn)

Comment: Just out of curiosity in case I'm missing something: How could any of the class templates ever be instantiated?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah, note the added **syntax-wise** part in bold in my answer. I wanted to show how to solve/correct the syntax problem that OP has in their program. Logical problems that they may have are a different thing/problem. I've added the *"The common way of doing this(syntax-wise)..."* so that OP and future readers know that this is a solution for the syntax problem that OP is facing. OP may realize the more underlying problem after some time though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo As you said in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77338630/compiling-c-non-type-template-parameters-outside-headers/77338642?noredirect=1#comment136342410_77338630), *"fundamental types have no bases and can not be bases"*

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid I missed something obvious. :-)

Comment: I used method 2 and it worked beautifully. Thank you!

Comment: @McFlurriez And how does it work when you try to create a `TestClass`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo May be OP have some other condition inside `enable_if` (that can result in a valid instantiation) and the code(`is_base_of`) example given in the question is for reproducing/showing the error purposes only. Though that is a pure speculation by looking at the name of the class `TestClass` in the given code. *Only OP can tell/clarify this.*

Comment: @user12002570 is right :-) I took a complicated example I was eyeballing and reduced it to this to help bring focus to the compilation issue.

Comment: @McFlurriez *"I took a complicated example I was eyeballing and reduced it to this"* -- This is good. May I suggest (for the future) a further simplification? Change `std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<int, U>>` to `std::enable_if_t<true>` and note the simplification either in the question or as a comment in the code.